# javascript: создать массив с заданными ключами через метод map

Tags: javascript, массивы, map

подскажите можно ли в JS решить следующую задачу (что называется в одну строку через map)

есть массив ключей:

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

необходимо создать массив где каждому ключу будет поставлено в соответствие некоторый элемент (для удобства в примере его индекс), т.е. на выходе должно получиться

```
{a:'0', b:'1', c:'2'}
```

Можно ли это сделать через `map`, что-то типа

```
res = arr.map((v, i) => {v: i})
```

?

Потому что не хочется делать такие вещи через циклы `for` или метод `forEach`

Comment: нет, это нельзя через `map` сделать, потому что `map` всегда возвращает массив, а ты хочешь получить объект.

Comment: @grundy, т.е. как предложил EzioMercer делать через reduce?

Comment: @да, можно так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен не `map`, а [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const obj = arr.reduce((result, el, index) => {
  result[el] = index + '';
  
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

Ну если нужно именно в 1 строку, то можно так:

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const obj = arr.reduce((result, el, index) => (result[el] = index + '', result), {});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: жаль что тоже не в 1 строчку :(

Comment: @Zhihar Так подойдёт?

Comment: более менее, просто привык к питоновским подходам :)

Comment: @Zhihar, ну... каждый выживает как может :)

Answer (score 1):

Для конкретного случая массива где нужно поменять ключи и значения местами можно использовать [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) и обратным методом [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const obj = Object.fromEntries( // собираем объект
  Object.entries(arr) // получаем список [[key, val], [key, val], ...]
  .map(([key, val]) => [val, key])); // меняем местами key и val [[val, key], [val, key], ...]

console.log(obj);
```